# Does anyone know the properties of Generalized Gaussian Distribution?

Tags: probability

The Generalized Gaussian density has the following form: $G(x; p)=\frac{1}{2\varGamma(1+1/p)}exp(-|x|^p)$.

Can anyone give some properties like the mean, variance, etc?

I took a look at wikipedia but found it hard to understand. Thanks.

Comment: Since https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution#Version_1  lists the parameters you mention, maybe you should specify what parts you find hard to understand.